# compare two hex files and use one file to create another

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have converted two binary files [Tintin.exe] & [Milo.exe] of same size and bytes "3Mb" each; To Hex values stored as [Tintin.txt] & [Milo.txt]  (each file now contains only hex numbers).

I need to find the difference between [Tintin.txt] & [Milo.txt] Then use  [Tintin.txt] To create [Milo.txt]

> Note that [Tintin.txt] & [Milo.txt] are 90% similar hence It would be
>   nice to save space by using one file to build another. (Saving 2.7 Mb
>   of space)

Comment: you could use a diff algorithm..

Comment: Look at [BinDiff](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509425/BinDiff-A-tool-to-compare-binary-files). It's an open source C# program that compares 2 binary files and writes a diff output. You should be able to do what you need by studying the code to that project.

Comment: I must do this in c#.

Comment: @Icemanind Thank you so much buddy! .. I was speaking to BugFinder

Comment: @Icemanind Add your answer so I can upvote you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BinDiff](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509425/BinDiff-A-tool-to-compare-binary-files). It's an open source C# Program that compares 2 binary files and writes a diff output. You should be able to do what you need by studying the code to that project.

Comment: The difference is 4Mb which is +33% filesize of the actual file :(

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder - Try zipping the difference file.